# My Selenium Webdriver cant locate a button no matter how I specify it

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm 'copying' Code from a Youtube Video ( https://github.com/aj-4/ig-followers/blob/master/main.py ) to get more familiar with Webdrivers.

I'm running Linux Mint and Chromium 85.

Its supposed to log into instagram with my user data and dismiss the two windows that come up with 'Not Now'. Logging in works perfectly and so does clicking the 'submit' button in the process, however my code fails to locate the two 'Not Now' buttons it has to click in order to proceed. I've tried to specify the button using the full XPath I copied by inspecting the button in Chromium (like i did with the submit button). Furthermore, specifying the button as `("//button[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]")` has not worked either. I also tried to do it using the buttons class (like shown here https://devhints.io/xpath ).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from logindata import un , pw


class instabot:
    def __init__(self, un, pw):
        link = ('https://www.instagram.com')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get(link)

    sleep(1)

    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"username\"]")\
        .send_keys(un)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"password\"]")\
        .send_keys(pw)

    sleep(1)

    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[3]/button/div")\
        .click()

    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]")\
        .click()

    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]")\
        .click()

    sleep(2)


    print('FINISH TESTING? [y/n]')

    input() == (X)
    if X == 'y':
        self.driver.close()
    else:
        sleep(30)

    instabot(un, pw)
```

No luck either. I get the same error every time.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "instabot.py", line 41, in <module>
    instabot(un, pw)
  File "instabot.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]")\
  File "/home/anton/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/home/anton/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/home/anton/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/anton/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.83)
```

I'm fairly new to coding, but even I know how to consult google.
This has not helped tho, so I'm turning to you guys. Every answer is appreciated sincerely.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add HTML and screenshot of page?

Answer (score 0):

Hi 'Not Now' is not being clicked as those are pop-up alerts which selenium cannot identify and click on 'Not Now'

Try using the below command,

driver.switch_to_alert().dismiss() # this will dismiss using 'Not Now' option